# Dismiss UITabBarController and Push Sign In View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm work on an application that needs to be constantly authenticated with a server, so I would like to save user credentials and then use it whenever necessary. Consequently when the user launch the application there is a verification checking for the credentials and then, if it is valid, proceeding the user to a UITabBarController. That way the user does not have to sign in every time the aplication is executed. Considering that, whenever user taps sign out I will need to push Sign In View Controller as well as dismiss UITabBarController. My question is How I'm going to dismiss UITabBarController? I don't think delegate is going to help since my Sign In View Controller don't even know about the UITabBarController and I can't make UITabBarController dismiss itself. Also I have a concern that if I don't dismiss UITabBarController its going to stay in memory.

I have drawn a diagram in order to clarify the scenario.

[image]

Thanks,
Marcos.

Comment: Please do some searching of questions on this site. This type of scenario is asked about very often.

Comment: @vilelam's scenario is pretty much what I'm looking for and given how long it took to find it, it's not asked about "very often".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1) Present the login view controller from the tabbar Controller

```
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
```

2) Each time change the root view controller of your application window:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

and then:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].window setRootViewController:loginViewController];
```

Comment: Is not risk just to simply presentViewController: loginViewController? I'm saying that because I'm not dismissing the tabBarController and it can impact o memory.

Comment: It is usually acceptable because you never instantiate more than one at the same time. But it's your choice

Answer (score 1):

Coming in a little late here, but my solution in a scenario nearly identical to yours was:

```
[tabBarController.moreNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```